# Is there a way to get application-specific directories?

Tags: rust, filesystems

Adobe AIR supports cross-platform properties like [`flash.filesystem.File.applicationDirectory`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory), which gives the application internal directory. There also the [storage directory](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory) and the [cache directory](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#cacheDirectory).

For example, the application storage directory looks like this on...:

- Windows: `file:///C:/Users/FooUser/AppData/Roaming/FooApp`
- Android: `file://sdcard/Android/com.foo.app`

I've considered the [`directories`](https://docs.rs/directories/4.0.1/directories/struct.ProjectDirs.html) crate, but it has a required parameter, the app name. How can I determine these directories, specially from a library (not the entry point code)?

Comment: you could take the app name as an argument from the app. after all, the app knows best what it wants to be called

Comment: Better yet, leave this question to the app; let it decide to use `directories` or similar. In general I don't think there's a reliable cross-platform way to find an "application-specific" directory since "application-specific" is just so vague.

Comment: @Coder-256 That's also a possibility. I've thought of using a mutable static variable `APP_ID`, but I think it's easier to leave it for the app to deal with as you said.